# Is English in the process of creating a nominative absolute in compound objects?

Tags: syntactic-analysis, nominative-vs-oblique

I have been observing the increasing frequency of the use of the nominative in cases such as:

1. Mary always has a huge disagreement with you and I.
2. If you have a problem at school, you can let your father or I know.
3. When you find the answer, be sure to tell Bob and I what you've learned.

People are not saying:

1. *Mary always has a huge disagreement with I.
2. *If you have a problem at school, you can let I know.
3. *When you find the answer, be sure to tell I what you've learned.

The key difference appears to be the presence of the "and" which has a curious effect on the case of the constituent parts of the compound object.

My initial supposition was that this is a hypercorrection, reacting to schoolteachers' correcting sentences like "Me and Bob went to the store" to "Bob and *I* went to the store" by simply saying "and I" whenever possible. This is made more possible by the distance between "I" and the preposition or verb before the compound object.

However, the nominative has been showing up in both parts of the compound object, even those with proximity to a transitive verb or preposition. All of the following have been found in student papers or online sources

1. During Rob's documentation of he and Beth's day...
2. My dad got tickets to the premiere of the new Star Wars tickets for he and I! Early birthday gift!!
3. Please stop asking what happened out of respect for she and I. Just know it’s over.
4. Ask not for whom it tolls. It tolls for he and she.
5. Nothing’s gonna change not for we and you
6. My friend jumps too. It is breathtaking how fearlessly – almost recklessly – she throws herself between he and I.
7. Indy wrestling was good tonight. Really good. Onto White River Wrestling tomorrow vs @twitterhandle for he and I’s second battle!
8. He promised the leader of the cult he and Rosemary’s baby in order to help his own acting career.

It is difficult to imagine even these speakers forming phrases like *I thought this was for he* and *Nothing’s gonna change for we*, and *He promised the leader of the cult he baby*. And yet, the proximity to the governing pronoun here does not seem to have done its work.

Is it possible that a new rule is emerging in which such compound objects are placed in a nominative bubble that is unaffected by the syntactical demands of the surrounding sentence:

1. My dad got tickets to the premiere of the new Star Wars tickets for {he and I}! Early birthday gift!!
2. Please stop asking what happened out of respect for {she and I}. Just know it’s over.
3. Ask not for whom it tolls. It tolls for {he and she}.
4. Nothing’s gonna change not for {we and you}

Any thoughts about what's going on?

Comment: This has been a common error for about 65 years that I know of.  Nothing new or particularly exciting.

Comment: ...possibly due to hyper-correction.

Comment: I don't think "a new rule is emerging".  These are expressions used by people who are probably incapable of learning rules.  Your examples are horrific!.

Comment: This Question must have duplicate in the hundreds.

Comment: @ab2 On British TV a few months ago I heard, in fairly quick succession, the Eton educated adventurer Bear Grylls and the Queen's neice Lady Sarah Chatto both use the "to <name> and I" form which always makes me cringe. However if an upper class background and a very expensive education doesn't eliminate it I'm afraid logic has lost the battle.

Comment: I don't see how this has anything to do with the "nominative absolute": my understanding is that "nominative absolute" is a term for a specific syntactic construction.

Comment: Sumelic, perhaps a better term than "nominative absolute" could be applied here. I used that because the parts of the compound object/coordinating phrase always appear to be in the nominative and unaffected by the surrounding parts, the way absolute constructions are. I grant that it's not entirely disconnected from the surrounding syntax, but it seems to operate by different rules. Perhaps "nominative bubble"?

Comment: Maybe "bubble" is a better term ... a similar but opposite phenomenon occurs with "me and", which I have seen people call a "disjunctive" use of the pronoun in analogy with languages like French (where "moi" is used in coordinated subjects).